# Magento Backend Catalog page keeps refreshing

Tags: magento

I have a magento install on a staging environment, everything is working except the catalog backend page and the frontend layered navigation. Look at the image below. There is a backend within the backend. When visiting the page it refreshes to infinity. [See this identical problem](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/298523/)

My first guess is there is a bug in the template file but an identical template file on my local machine does not cause any issues. Additionally the database between my local and staging site are identical minus the core_config_url. The only difference is local I am running Apache and on staging I am running nginx.

The second issue which I imagine is related is that the filters on the frontend catalog page dont work. They are visible but clicking on them  reloads the page without changing the products.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

UPDATE: After switching from NGINX to Apache the issue disappeared. I still would like to figure out what is causing the problem

[image]

Comment: What response to you get from the AJAX calls that keep repeating? Do you have any extensions related to categories? If you do, try disabling them for tests. Did you change the theme of your admin?

Comment: We also facing the same issue with nginx, but works in Apache local set up, But we can not move to apache2 in production. Do you have solutions for this.

Comment: @Mohsin. I think I just switched to Apache, and never solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I take for granted that you had already tried different browsers/clearing your browser cache and Magento cache (empty the cache directory), etc.

Are you sure you put the correct value in the cookie_domain setting? Many users that had your same problem seem to have setted up an incorrect value in that setting.
Take a look [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/34489/) and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that usually this is caused by a server-side error on the ajax request. If there is any kind of error response returned, it will just continue to spin. Either check your Chrome console for a 500 response, or look in your server's error logs.